# Predicting single images with tensorflow dataset api

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to create a prediction script using the tensorflow dataset api. Previously I did this using the low-level API and feed_dict:

```
#import graph
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('...')

# Select variables to feed
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")
predictions = graph.get_tensor_by_name("pred:0")

with tf.Session() as sess:
   p = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={x:x_feed})
```

Now I am using the dataset API in the fashion below:

```
iterator = 
   tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_dataset.output_types,
                                       training_dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(training_dataset)
validation_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(validation_dataset)


for _ in range(20):
 # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
  sess.run(training_init_op)
  for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(next_element
 # Initialize an iterator over the validation dataset.
  sess.run(validation_init_op)
  for _ in range(50):
    sess.run(next_element)
```

I am saving a .meta and .data file. **How do I use these to create a prediction script?** I am unable to extract operations from the graph and feed in desired vales an there are no placeholders defined. One way would be to use the same script and use test data, but there must be a better way?

Thanks